# Windows Phone SDK 8 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-7-x64

i m using Visual studio 2015 and i need to install Windows Phone SDK 8 on Windows 7. I know that Windows Phone sdk 8

> •Supported Operating System Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro
>
> •Operating system type: Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions
>
> •Hardware:
>   6.5 GB of free hard disk space 4 GB RAM 64-bit (x64) CPU

i try [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2422751) but it does not work i think that this method is for Visual Studio 2012. So it's possible to install SDK8 on Windows 7 ? if yes How ?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to Windows 10, for which there is support for building Windows Phone 8.x apps

Comment: Nop i prefer to work in Windows 7. But i think that is my last solution

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 SDK is not compatibile with windows 7